# What might $.event.handle.apply mean in jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What might $.event.handle.apply mean in jQuery code?

Answer (score 3):

`jQuery.event.handle()` is an internal jQuery method, used by the library to create and filter things like `event namespaces`. I wouldn't know why someone would ever call it manually, but what do I know ?

`.apply()` is a way in ECMA-/Javascript to invoke a function in a **specific Context**. It takes two arguments:

- an object which serves as the Context
- an array which represent the optional arguments

Example:

```
$.event.handle.apply(this, [event]);
```

This would execute the `handle function` in the **Context** of **this** (of course, that can vary) and passes in a single argument **event** (variable).